# Using SPServices to get Choice Column options

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, spservices

I would like to create a custom modal that has the same drop down items that are contained in the choice column when adding a new item. My page is a custom .html and does not load the default SharePoint files. My column name is

```
Entry: Notice or Information or Error
```

I used this example as a starting point [SPServices: populate a drop-down menu](http://www.bentedder.com/spservices-example-populate-a-drop-down-menu/)
I have it working, however I wanted the choices contained in the column so that the modal will have them as well. Any direction is appreciated my Google results haven’t really retuned anything using just SPServices.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with a choice field. It would be if you store the choices in another list and make the field a lookup.

Comment: Try this: https://devspoint.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/using-spservices-to-get-the-values-of-a-choice-field/